# resourcemanager web ui does not show job status

Tags: hadoop

I have just configured a hadoop clustering by using cdh5.I could  successful run  test jobs in command line and get the results.resourcemanager ui doesnot show job status,even in the completion .If I set mapreduce.framework.name to yarn in mapred-site.xml and job fails and show failure status in the resourcemanager ui.

Test job,I have used to run
yarn jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.0-cdh5.3.1.jar pi 16 10000

Here is my yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.enabled</name>
   <value>true</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id</name>
   <value>cluster1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.rm-ids</name>
   <value>rm1,rm2</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm1</name>
   <value>rhel2</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm2</name>
   <value>rhel3</value>
 </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.automatic-failover.embedded</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.recovery.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.store.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.ZKRMStateStore</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.zk.state-store.address</name>
    <value>localhost:2181</value>
  </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.zk-address</name>
   <value>rhel2.had.com:2181,rhel3.had.com:2181,rhel4.had.com:2181</value>
 </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.scheduler.connection.wait.interval-ms</name>
    <value>5000</value>
  </property>
<property>
<name>yarn.web-proxy.address</name>
<value>rhel2:9046</value>
</property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>



<!-- Node Config -->
  <property>
    <description>Address where the localizer IPC is.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:23344</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <description>NM Webapp address.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:23999</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
    <value>/tmp/pseudo-dist/yarn/local</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
    <value>/tmp/pseudo-dist/yarn/log</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.shuffle.port</name>
    <value>23080</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I didn't set any parameter in mapred-site.xml and the file is empty

Please let me know,any changes to be done to mapred-site.xml or yarn-site.xml file to get web ui worked